# Spring Integration error: Failure to write to 'foo/002.txt.writing' while uploading the file

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, messaging, spring-integration-dsl

I'm experimenting with the following sample setup from [SI samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/main/applications/file-split-ftp/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/samples/filesplit/Application.java) to understand its inner workings with a goal to then adapt it to similar set of tasks in upper environments.

**DailyCashReportApplication.java**

```
@Slf4j
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:feeds-config.yml", factory = com.pru.globalpayments.feeds.downstream.YamlPropertySourceFactory.class)
public class DailyCashReportApplication  implements CommandLineRunner  {
    
//  @Autowired
//  @Qualifier("syntheticRunner") //TODO: to be replaced by runners consuming from appropriate data sources
//  private AbstractRunner runner; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        log.info("DailyCashReportApplication running...");
    
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(DailyCashReportApplication.class).web(WebApplicationType.NONE).run(args);
        
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        //runner.run(args);
    }
```

**DcrConfig.java**:

```
@Configuration
public class DcrConfig {

    private final static String EMAIL_SUCCESS_SUFFIX = "emailSuccessSuffix";
    
    // sftp

    @Value("${sftp.in.host}")
    @Getter
    private String host;

    @Value("${sftp.in.port}")
    private int port;

    @Value("${sftp.in.user}")
    private String user;

    @Value("${sftp.in.privateKey}")
    @Getter
    private String privateKeyLocation;

    @Value("${sftp.in.remoteDir}")
    @Getter
    private String remoteDir;



    @Value("${sftp.in.localDir}")
    @Getter
    private String localDir;

    @Value("${sftp.in.chmod}")
    private String chmod;

    @Value("${sftp.in.maxFetchSize}")
    @Getter
    private int maxFetchSize;

    @Value("${sftp.in.file.filter}")
    private String fileFilter;

    @Autowired
    private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;
    
    @Bean(name = "downloadSftpSessionFactory")
    public SessionFactory<LsEntry> sftpSessionFactory() throws IOException {

        Resource keyFileResource = resourceLoader.getResource(privateKeyLocation);

        DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory();
        factory.setHost(host);
        factory.setPort(port);
        factory.setUser(user);
        factory.setPrivateKey(keyFileResource);
        factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
        return new CachingSessionFactory<LsEntry>(factory);
    }

    
    
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow fromFile() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Files.inboundAdapter(new File(remoteDir))
                                        .preventDuplicates(false)
                                        .patternFilter("*.txt"), 
                e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(5000))
                                        .id("fileInboundChannelAdapter"))
                .handle(Files.splitter(true, true))
                .<Object, Class<?>>route(Object::getClass, m->m
                        .channelMapping(FileSplitter.FileMarker.class, "markers.input")
                        .channelMapping(String.class, "lines.input"))
                .get();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public FileWritingMessageHandlerSpec fileOut() {
        return Files.outboundAdapter("'"+localDir+"'")
                .appendNewLine(true)
                .fileNameExpression("payload.substring(1,4) + '.txt'");
    }
    
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow lines(FileWritingMessageHandler fileOut) {
        return f -> f.handle(fileOut); 
    }
    

    
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow markers() throws IOException{
        return f -> f.<FileSplitter.FileMarker>filter(m -> m.getMark().equals(FileSplitter.FileMarker.Mark.END),
                        e -> e.id("markerFilter"))
                .publishSubscribeChannel(s -> s

                        // first trigger file flushes
                        .subscribe(sf -> sf.transform("'tmp/out/.*\\.txt'", e -> e.id("toTriggerPattern"))
                                .trigger("fileOut", e -> e.id("flusher")))

                        // send the first file
                        .subscribe(sf -> {
                            try {
                                sf.<FileSplitter.FileMarker, File>transform(p -> new File("tmp/out/002.txt"))
                                        .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header(FileHeaders.FILENAME, "002.txt", true))
                                        .handle(Sftp.outboundAdapter(ftp()).remoteDirectory("foo"), e -> e.id("ftp002"));
                            } catch (IOException e1) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        })

                        // send the second file
                        .subscribe(sf -> {
                            try {
                                sf.<FileSplitter.FileMarker, File>transform(p -> new File("/tmp/out/006.txt"))
                                        .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header(FileHeaders.FILENAME, "006.txt", true))
                                        .handle(Sftp.outboundAdapter(ftp()).remoteDirectory("foo"), e -> e.id("ftp006"));
                            } catch (IOException e1) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        })

                        // send the third file
                        .subscribe(sf -> {
                            try {
                                sf.<FileSplitter.FileMarker, File>transform(p -> new File("/tmp/out/009.txt"))
                                        .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header(FileHeaders.FILENAME, "009.txt", true))
                                        .handle(Sftp.outboundAdapter(ftp()).remoteDirectory("foo"), e -> e.id("ftp009"));
                            } catch (IOException e1) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        })


                        );
    }
    

    
    

    

    
    @Bean
    public SessionFactory<LsEntry> ftp() throws IOException {

        Resource keyFileResource = resourceLoader.getResource(privateKeyLocation);


        DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory();
        factory.setHost(host);
        factory.setPort(port);
        factory.setUser(user);
        factory.setPrivateKey(keyFileResource);
        factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
        return new CachingSessionFactory<LsEntry>(factory);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public MethodInterceptor afterMailAdvice() {
        return invocation -> {
            Message<?> message = (Message<?>) invocation.getArguments()[0];
            MessageHeaders headers = message.getHeaders();
            File originalFile = headers.get(FileHeaders.ORIGINAL_FILE, File.class);
            try {
                invocation.proceed();
                originalFile.renameTo(new File(originalFile.getAbsolutePath() + headers.get(EMAIL_SUCCESS_SUFFIX)));
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                originalFile.renameTo(new File(originalFile.getAbsolutePath() + headers.get(EMAIL_SUCCESS_SUFFIX)+"email.failed"));
            }
            return null;
        };
    }
    
}
```

**application-dev.yml**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: daily-cash-report-application

sftp:
  in:
    host: eafdev
    port: 22
    user: eafdev
    remoteDir: tmp/in 
    tmpDir: 
    localDir: tmp/out 
    maxFetchSize: 1    
    privateKey: file:///C:/Users/x12345/AppData/Roaming/SSH/UserKeys/distributessh
    chmod: 664 
    poller:
      fixedDelay: 10000
    file:
      filter: A.B.*    #TODO: calibrate once spec is known
  out:
    host: eafdev
    port: 22
    user: eafdev
    remoteDir: tmp/out  
    privateKey: file:///C:/Users/x12345/AppData/Roaming/SSH/UserKeys/distributessh
    chmod: 664 

file: 
  out:   
    targetDir: 
    tmpDir:
```

**DailyCashReportApplicationTest.java**:

```
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@SpringIntegrationTest(noAutoStartup = "fileInboundChannelAdapter")
@SpringJUnitConfig(classes = { 
        DailyCashReportApplication.class,
        DcrConfig.class,
        })
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@PropertySource(value = "application-dev.yml", factory = YamlPropertySourceFactory.class)
@Slf4j
class DailyCashReportApplicationTest {

    @Test
    @SneakyThrows
    void test()  {

        File in = new File("tmp/in/", "foo");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(in);
        fos.write("*002,foo,bar\n*006,baz,qux\n*009,fiz,buz\n".getBytes());
        fos.close();
        in.renameTo(new File("tmp/in/", "foo.txt"));

        File out = new File("tmp/out/002.txt");
        int n = 0;
        while (n++ < 100 && (!out.exists() || out.length() < 12)) {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
        assertThat(out.exists()).isTrue();

    }

}
```

Regardless if run via *ApplicationTest.java, or via executing the above *Application.java file in the IDE and dropping the same foo.txt content in the pre-created `tmp/in` folder, I'm seeing **partially** correct behavior in terms of `tmp\in\foo.txt` being picked up and 3 files being created in the `tmp/out` accompanied by the following error:

```
2023-09-20 11:40:21.384 [scheduling-1] ERROR o.s.i.handler.LoggingHandler - org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Error handling message for file [C:\code\STS\daily-cash-report\tmp\out\002.txt -> 002.txt]; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to write to 'foo/002.txt.writing' while uploading the file; nested exception is java.io.IOException: failed to write file, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=tmp\out\002.txt, headers={file_lineCount=3, file_name=002.txt, file_originalFile=tmp\in\foo.txt, id=365e346c-78d4-47ab-d6c0-e4f0f5f72f43, file_marker=END, file_relativePath=foo.txt, timestamp=1695224420443}]
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.doSend(RemoteFileTemplate.java:368)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.lambda$send$0(RemoteFileTemplate.java:314)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:452)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.send(RemoteFileTemplate.java:314)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.send(RemoteFileTemplate.java:302)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.send(RemoteFileTemplate.java:294)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.handler.FileTransferringMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(FileTransferringMessageHandler.java:207)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:55)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:456)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.doProduceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:324)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:267)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:231)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:142)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:55)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:456)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.doProduceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:324)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:267)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:231)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:142)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:55)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:456)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.doProduceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:324)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:267)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:231)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:142)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:55)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.invokeHandler(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:222)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.BroadcastingDispatcher.dispatch(BroadcastingDispatcher.java:178)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:456)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.doProduceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:324)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:267)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:231)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:142)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:55)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMessageRouter.doSend(AbstractMessageRouter.java:213)
    at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMessageRouter.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageRouter.java:195)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:55)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:456)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.doProduceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:324)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:267)
    at org.springframework.integration.splitter.AbstractMessageSplitter.produceOutput(AbstractMessageSplitter.java:317)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:231)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:142)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:55)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.handleMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:196)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.messageReceived(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:474)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:460)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.pollForMessage(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:412)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$createPoller$4(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:347)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$createPoller$5(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:340)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to write to 'foo/002.txt.writing' while uploading the file; nested exception is java.io.IOException: failed to write file
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.sendFileToRemoteDirectory(RemoteFileTemplate.java:573)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.doSend(RemoteFileTemplate.java:353)
    ... 127 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: failed to write file
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.write(SftpSession.java:175)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory$CachedSession.write(CachingSessionFactory.java:237)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.doSend(RemoteFileTemplate.java:582)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.sendFileToRemoteDirectory(RemoteFileTemplate.java:570)
    ... 128 more
Caused by: 2: No such file
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2873)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._put(ChannelSftp.java:594)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.put(ChannelSftp.java:540)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.put(ChannelSftp.java:492)
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.write(SftpSession.java:172)
    ... 131 more
```

The gist seems to be: `Failed to write to 'foo/002.txt.writing' while uploading the file; nested exception is java.io.IOException: failed to write file, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=tmp\out\002.txt, headers={file_lineCount=3, file_name=002.txt, file_originalFile=tmp\in\foo.txt, id=365e346c-78d4-47ab-d6c0-e4f0f5f72f43, file_marker=END, file_relativePath=foo.txt, timestamp=1695224420443}]`

It is thrown on a brand-new file being dropped in the `tmp\in` folder and then repeatedly on every  poller execution while the split into the 3 resulting files: `002.txt`, `006.txt` and `009.txt` happens correctly, as mentioned above.

I'm aware of the `.writing` extension (as per [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/file.html#file-incomplete)), however this doesn't seem like an expected behavior.  While playing with that SI sample, I'd like to get to the bottom of why this error is happening so I can eliminate it migrating the app from this experimental environment into the real ones.

Comment: I think it fails because there is that `foo` remote directory on your SFTP server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It fails because there is just no that `foo` remote directory to upload file into.

See `autoCreateDirectory(true)` option:

```
/**
 * A {@code boolean} flag to indicate automatically create the directory or not.
 * @param autoCreateDirectory true to automatically create the directory.
 * @return the current Spec
 */
public S autoCreateDirectory(boolean autoCreateDirectory) {
```

It is `false` by default on the `RemoteFileTemplate`.

Therefore your config must be like this:

```
Sftp.outboundAdapter(ftp()).remoteDirectory("foo").autoCreateDirectory(true)
```